# onpopstate and pushstate not working - can't spot why

Tags: javascript, back-button, pushstate, popstate

This is not a duplicate question, I cannot find the help I need. I would appreciate advice as to why my following code is not working please.

```
  window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
  if (!cookieExists()) {
    showAlerts();
    countDownTimer();
    document.cookie = `${cookieName}=true;max-age=604800;SameSite=None; Secure`;
  }
});

window.history.pushState({}, "", "/");
```

For context, when the user hits the browser back button, my alerts should show.

Edit: I have updated my code and it still doesn't work. When I click back, it just goes back to the previous page. When I refresh I get an 'oops something went wrong' is there a way to test in the console?

Comment: `history.back()` doesn't return anything, so your `if` will never be executed. Btw, you don't have to call `.back()` in a `popstate` event...

Comment: Thank you. :) I wonder if my push state is in the wrong place, I don't think it will be recognised outside of popstate?

Comment: What do you mean? Your `.pushState` is OK.

Comment: Okay, I was just checking as I'm trying to understand. Can anyone help? I have edited my question.